# Data structure of memoization in db

Tags: python, database-design, data-structures, memoization

What is the best data structure to cache (save/store/memorize) so many function result in database. 
Suppose function calc_regress with flowing definition in python:

```
def calc_regress(ind_key, dep_key, count=30):
    independent_list = sql_select_recent_values(count, ind_key)
    dependant_list = sql_select_recent_values(count, dep_key)
    import scipy.stats as st
    return st.linregress(independent_list, dependant_list)
```

I see answers to [What kind of table structure should be used to store memoized function parameters and results in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147972/what-kind-of-table-structure-should-be-used-to-store-memoized-function-parameter) but it seem to resolve problem of just one function while I have about 500 function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option A**

You could use the structure in the linked answer, un-normalized with the number of columns = max number of arguments among the 500 functions. Also need to add a column for the function name.

Then you could do a `SELECT * FROM expensive_func_results WHERE func_name = 'calc_regress' AND arg1 = ind_key AND arg2 = dep_key and arg3 = count`, etc.

Ofcourse, that's not a very good design to use. For the same function called with fewer parameters, columns with null values/non-matches need to be ignored; otherwise you'll get multiple result rows.

**Option B**

Create the table/structure as `func_name`, `arguments`, `result` where 'arguments' is always a kwargs dictionary or positional args but not mixed per entry. Even with the kwargs dict stored as a string, order of keys->values in it is not predictable/consistent even if it's the same args. So you'll need to order it before converting to a string and storing it. When you want to query, you'll use `SELECT * FROM expensive_func_results WHERE func_name = 'calc_regress' AND arguments = 'str(kwargs_dict)'`, where `str(kwargs_dict)` is something you'll set programmatically. It could also be set to the result of [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec), (or [`inspect.getcallargs`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcallargs)) though you'll have to check for consistency.

You won't be able to do queries on the argument combos unless you provide all the arguments to the query or partial match with `LIKE`.

**Option C**

Normalised all the way: One table `func_calls` as `func_name`, `args_combo_id`, `arg_name_idx`, `arg_value`. Each row of the table will store one arg for one combo of that function's calling args. Another table `func_results` as `func_name`, `args_combo_id`, `result`. You could also normalise further for `func_name` to be mapped to a `func_id`.

In this one, the order of keyword args doesn't matter since you'll be doing an Inner join to select each parameter. This query will have to be built programmatically or done via a stored procedure, since the number of joins required to fetch all the parameters is determined by the number of parameters. Your function above has 3 params but you may have another with 10. `arg_name_idx` is 'argument name or index' so it also works for mixed kwargs + args. Some duplication may occur in cases like `calc_regress(ind_key=1, dep_key=2, count=30)` and `calc_regress(1, 2, 30)` (as well as `calc_regress(1, 2)` with a default value for count <-- this cases should be avoided, the table entry should have all args); since the `args_combo_id` will be different for both but result will obviously be the same. Again, the inspect module may help in this area.

---

*[Edit]* PS: Additionally, for the `func_name`, you may need to use a fully qualified name to avoid conflicts across modules in your package. And decorators may interfere with that as well; without a `deco.__name__ = func.__name__`, etc.

PPS: If objects are being passed to functions being memoized in the db, make sure that their `__str__` is something useful & repeatable/consistent to store as arg values.

This particular case doesn't require you to re-create objects from the arg values in the db, otherwise, you'd need to make `__str__` or `__repr__` like the way [`__repr__` was intended to be](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (but isn't generally done):

> this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment).

Comment: I prefer part C, but I have some concern about it: what if I refactor some part of my code? It seems saving results is like freezing your code in db! 

  is memorization a right thing to do? (according software engineering principles)  if any refactoring occurs, I should re calculate those functions again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a key value storage here, where the key could be a concatenation of the `id` of the function object (to guarantee the key uniqness) and its arguments while the value would be the function returned value.

So `calc_regress(1, 5, 30)` call would produce an example  key `139694472779248_1_5_30` where the first part is `id(calc_regress)`. An example key producing function:

```
>>> def produce_cache_key(fun, *args, **kwargs):
...     args_key = '_'.join(str(a) for a in args)
...     kwargs_key = '_'.join('%s%s' % (k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items())
...     return '%s_%s_%s' % (id(fun), args_key, kwargs_key)
```

You could keep your results in memory using a dictionary and a decorator:

```
>>> def cache_result(cache):
...     def decorator(fun):
...         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...             key = produce_cache_key(fun, *args, **kwargs)
...             if key not in cache:
...                 cache[key] = fun(*args, **kwargs)
...             return cache[key]
...         return wrapper
...     return decorator
... 
>>> 
>>> @cache_result(cache_dict)
... def fx(x, y, z=0):
...     print 'Doing some expensive job...'
... 
>>> cache = {}
>>> fx(1, 2, z=1)
Doing some expensive job...
>>> fx(1, 2, z=1)
>>>
```

Comment: Is your solution like part B of aneroid's answer with having joint primary key of `func_name`, `arguments`?

Comment: Please see my edit, I have provided an example implementation using python dictionary.